# variable with negative exponent in the denominator moved to nominator and vice versa

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

The top and bottom of the fraction both contain negative exponents. Since $c^{-3}$ on the bottom has a negative exponent, it is moved to the top of the fraction (numerator). Since the $d^{-3}$ on the top of the fraction has a negative exponent, it is moved to the bottom of the fraction (denominator).
$$\frac{d^{-3}} {c^{-3}}$$
to
$$\frac{c^3} {d^3}$$
Any explanation why does this happen?

Comment: It comes from the rule $a^{b-c} = \frac{a^b}{a^c}$ Applying that rule   $a^{-3} = a^{0-3} = \frac{a^0}{a^3} = \frac{1}{a^3}$

Comment: Is the edit giving what you intended.  If so, you could at least use the ^ to indicate powers and parentheses to provide grouping.  Even better, write it in $\LaTeX$.  An intro is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the laws of exponents is $a^{-b}=\frac 1{a^b}$.  So the $d^{-3}$ in the numerator is equal to $\frac 1{d^3}$ and $\frac 1{c^{-3}}=c^3$.  Putting them together gives what you are asking about.

Comment: so typically what will happen is something like this? 1/d^3 / 1/c^3 ?

Comment: Yes, if you mean $\frac {d^{-3}}{c^{-3}}=\dfrac {\frac 1{d^3}}{\frac 1{c^3}}=\frac {c^3}{d^3}$.  Please use parentheses when you use slashes.  One can guess where the main division should be, but we shouldn't need to guess.

Comment: Yup. that one. sorry, I am new here I don't here the shortcuts. from here 1/d^3 (/) 1/c^3  how did it came to c^3/d^3

Comment: @Dave:  You multiply numerator and denominator by $c^3d^3$  It is the usual technique to clear four level fractions like this-multiply by the product of the denominators.

Comment: Finally got it. Thanks.